# Association references unmapped class: com.service.hibernate.entities.Connetion

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Sorry for bothering you. I'm newbie with hibernate and I have problem with mapping. I think that it'll be stupid mistake but I'm not able to deal with this problem on my own. I won't decribe whole database (it's too big), ... only part with mistake. I have 2 tables. First one with name "Accounts":

```
CREATE TABLE `accounts` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nick` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `firstname` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `secondname` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sex` binary(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `birth` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `about` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `photo` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `profesion` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `interests` varchar(70) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `login_timestamp` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `temporal_hash` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `permission_id` int(2) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `mail` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `language_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `backup_mail` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=big5;
```

This table has one-to-many relationship with table "connection"

```
CREATE TABLE `connection` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `host` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf32;
```

column "user_id" identifies the user account.

Here is the mapping XML file for Accounts entity:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.service.hibernate.entities.Accounts" table="accounts">
        <id name="id" column="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="nick" type="java.lang.String" column="nick"/>
        <property name="password" type="java.lang.String" column="password"/>
        <property name="firstname" type="java.lang.String" column="firstname" />          
        <property name="secondname" type="java.lang.String" column="secondname"/>       
        <property name="sex" type="java.lang.Boolean" column="sex"/>        
        <property name="birth" type="java.util.Date" column="birth"/>  
        <property name="about" type="java.lang.String" column="about"/> 
        <property name="photo" type="java.lang.String" column="photo"/>     
        <property name="profesion" type="java.lang.String" column="profesion"/>     
        <property name="interests" type="java.lang.String" column="interests"/> 
        <property name="address" type="java.lang.String" column="address"/> 
        <property name="login_timestamp" type="java.util.Date" column="login_timestamp"/> 
        <property name="temporal_hash" type="java.lang.String" column="temporal_hash"/>    
        <property name="phone" type="java.lang.String" column="phone"/> 
        <property name="mail" type="java.lang.String" column="mail"/> 
        <property name="backup_mail" type="java.lang.String" column="backup_mail"/>

        .
        .
        .

        <!-- CONNECTION LOG - KURVA NECHAPEM. NIE A NIE NAPAMPOVAT TU POSRANU ENTITU. O CO JE INAKSIA AKO NAPR FORUM ???  -->
        <set name="connections" table="connection" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key column="user_id" />
            <one-to-many class="com.service.hibernate.entities.Connetion" />
        </set>

        .
        .
        .

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

- I removed unimportant parts and replaced them with dots.

Here is the mapping XML file for "Connection" entity:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.service.hibernate.entities.Connection" table="connection">
        <id name="id" column="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="host" type="java.lang.String" column="host"/>
        <property name="date" type="java.util.Date" column="date"/>
        <property name="description" type="java.lang.String" column="description"/> 
        <property name="user_id" type="java.lang.Integer" column="user_id"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">qayxsw</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema">training</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</property>

         .
         .
         .        

        <mapping resource="com/service/hibernate/map_xml/Accounts.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="com/service/hibernate/map_xml/Connection.hbm.xml"/>

         .
         .
         .

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Here is the error message:

```
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.MappingException: Association references unmapped class: com.service.hibernate.entities.Connetion
null
Mar 31, 2015 6:45:26 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException
SEVERE: The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.service.utils.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:20)
    at com.service.utils.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:9)
    at com.service.user.UserServices.userAuthentication(UserServices.java:221)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Association references unmapped class: com.service.hibernate.entities.Connetion
    at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.bindCollectionSecondPass(HbmBinder.java:2577)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder$CollectionSecondPass.secondPass(HbmBinder.java:2828)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.originalSecondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1697)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1426)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1846)
    at com.service.utils.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:15)
    ... 44 more

Mar 31, 2015 6:45:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Jersey] in context with path [/RESTfulWebService] threw exception [java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError] with root cause
org.hibernate.MappingException: Association references unmapped class: com.service.hibernate.entities.Connetion
    at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.bindCollectionSecondPass(HbmBinder.java:2577)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder$CollectionSecondPass.secondPass(HbmBinder.java:2828)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.originalSecondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1697)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1426)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1846)
    at com.service.utils.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:15)
    at com.service.utils.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:9)
    at com.service.user.UserServices.userAuthentication(UserServices.java:221)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Error says that: Association references unmapped class: com.service.hibernate.entities.Connetion

but I don't think that there is the mistake :(. Funny thing is that I have more that 6 one-to-many relations in database but only this one doesn't work. I can't find the difference between them :D

Class Connection:

```
package com.service.hibernate.entities;

import java.util.Date;

public class Connection implements java.io.Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8191028135531498491L;

    private Integer id = null;

    private String host = null;

    private Date date = null;

    private String description = null;

    private Integer user_id = null;

    public Connection(){
        this(null,null,null,null,null);
    }

    public Connection(Integer id, String host, Date date, String description, Integer user_id) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.host = host;
        this.date = date;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getHost() {
        return host;
    }

    public void setHost(String host) {
        this.host = host;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Integer getUser_id() {
        return user_id;
    }

    public void setUser_id(Integer user_id) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help :). Best Regards

Comment: `Connetion != Connection`. You wouldn't have to duplicate class and properties names in XML files if you abandoned XML mapping and used annotations instead. XML was cool when we used Java 1.4.

Comment: @JBNizer Thanks. Please can you show me where is the incompatibility between Connection.java and Connection mapping file ? Annotations are the last option. I want to avoid modifying all of them (and of course i'm lazy :D)

Comment: You're using `Connetion` instead of `Connection` in the mapping XML file for the Accounts entity. Fix the spelling.

Comment: @JBNizer Damn i knew that it will be the stupid mistake :D. I had to read those 2 words 6 times while i realised it :D. Thanks so much :))